# AWS S3 : Get Last Modified Timestamp Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have written a java code to get the list of files in a AWS S3 bucket's folder as a list of strings. Is there any direct function that I could use to get the last modified timestamp of a file that we see in the s3 buckets.

Comment: s3 examples( LISTING A BUCKET’S CONTENT) found at: [http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/java/](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/java/)

Answer (score 10):

You can get the `lastModified` as a `java.util.Date` via the [S3ObjectSummary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html) object.

```java
// ...
ListObjectsV2Request listObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    .withBucketName("my-bucket")
    .withMaxKeys(1000);

ListObjectsV2Result result = s3client.listObjectsV2(listObjectsV2Request);

for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
    // objectSummary.getLastModified() as java.util.Date
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know the last modified timestamp of a specific file without listing the whole directory you can use a `GetObjectRequest` and then retrieve from it the ObjectMetadata. Here is an example:

```
S3Object fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, remoteFilePath));
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = fullObject.getObjectMetadata();
Date lastModified = objectMetadata.getLastModified();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use [minio-java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java) client library for same. Its Open Source and compatible with AWS S3 API.

Using [ListBuckets](https://docs.minio.io/docs/java-client-api-reference#listBuckets) API, you can easily implement it.

```
try {
  // List buckets that have read access.
  List bucketList = minioClient.listBuckets();
  for (Bucket bucket : bucketList) {
      System.out.println(bucket.creationDate() + ", " + bucket.name());
  }
} catch (MinioException e) {
  System.out.println("Error occured: " + e);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)

Comment: You should answer "Last *Modified* Timestamp" instead of creationDate